# Redirecting Users from Unauthorized Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, forms-authentication, federated-identity

I have an MVC application that I recently converted the authentication/authorization method from forms to federated.  Everything works fine, but on the home page I have to create a cookie for the authorization of the rest of my site to work properly.  When users navigate to the home page first it works great, if they navigate to a different page first where authorization is required they get a 401 unauthorized error page.

When I had the forms authentication implemented it would redirect users that were unauthorized to the login page, with federation I no longer have a login page so I would like to redirect to the home page.  With forms authentication the redirection was automatic, how would I setup something similar for my federated application?

Here are the federated portions of my web.config that are relevant.  Again, federated authentication/authorization works, just the unauthorized redirect that isn't.

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionProtection="Secure" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionStringName="ADConn" connectionUsername="UName" connectionPassword="Pass" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ADLibraryROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="1440" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="true" cookieProtection="All">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ADConn" connectionUsername="UName" connectionPassword="Pass" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" type="MyApp.ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
      <modules>
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://fed.example.com/"/>
      </audienceUris>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="http://myfedservice.example.com/adfs/services/trust">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="mythumb"/>
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="http://fed.example.com/adfs/services/trust"/>
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true"/>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://fed.example.com/adfs/ls/" realm="https://fed.example.com/" reply="https://fed.example.com/" requireHttps="true" persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: I tried to create a custom redirect, I check for authorization (which appears to be working) and if not authorized I redirect to my home page where the federation cookie gets create.  Problem is when the user is unauthorized rather than redirecting home like I expected I get a "website has a redirect loop" error.  Why would this happen??

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this in the `wsFederation` section, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568657%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further details. By setting the “passiveRedirectEnabled”  to true, the WSFederationAuthenticationModule will look at all outgoing responses, trying to find HTTP 401s. If it finds a 401, it will modify the response and turn it into a redirect to the STS. Please note that in production you want to change `requireHttps` to `true`.

```
<system.identityModel.services>
<federationConfiguration>
  <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" 
    issuer="http://localhost:15839/wsFederationSTS/Issue" 
    realm="http://localhost:50969/" reply="http://localhost:50969/" 
    requireHttps="false" 
    signOutReply="http://localhost:50969/SignedOutPage.html" 
    signOutQueryString="Param1=value2&amp;Param2=value2" 
    persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" />
  <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
</federationConfiguration>
```

Please note that you also need to add these modules:

```
<modules>
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

and the following config sections:

```
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

Comment: I have everything except the signOutReply and signOutQueryString and it doesn't work are those necessary?  I don't know what I would put in the query string, and I don't have a sign out page currently.

Comment: You can omit those, they are not required. Please check http://chris.59north.com/post/Configuring-an-ASPNET-site-to-use-WS-Federation for further details.

Comment: I seem to have everything suggested in the blog you linked too, but still no redirection.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: What authentication mode have you enabled in IIS ? You should have enabled anonymous authentication.

Comment: Correct, only anonymous is enabled.  I assume without it federation wouldn't work at all.  Federated authentication works great, just won't redirect when a user tries to access a page they are not authorized to view.

Comment: another question, I see where you set allow the redirect via "passiveRedirectEnabled" but I don't see where you actually set the page to redirect to does it use the realm? Or could that be the problem, it doesn't know where to redirect to?

Comment: It redirects to the audienceUris, see the blog post I provided

Comment: posting relevant portions of my web.config, maybe someone can see the issue that I seem to be missing.

Comment: Worked for me!!  Wow, sometimes I wish I would google things earlier rather than spinning my wheels for so long.